# Operator which commutes with every translation also commutes with convolutions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

I am currently trying to prove that every bounded $T:L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ which commutes with translations must be a Fourier multiplier. I've seen a few posts that deal with this question and there are some good answers which are convincing to me.

That being said, the exercise **I** was given, was to prove as a **first** step that such an operator must commute with any convolution operator with a function $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

The weird thing is - I am unsure as to what does this commutation mean. The notation $g*(Tf)(x)$ is clear but what does $T(g*f)(x)$ even say?

I though about "skipping" this and trying to work with the Fourier transform of $T$, but got nothing usefull so far (I understand that there is a better way to prove the theorem, but I'm really curious to know what was the intention of said exercise).

Comment: $T(g*f)(x)$: Take the convolution of $g$ with $f$; this gives a function. Apply $T$ on this function; this gives another function. Take its value at $x$.